# Loading animation on lagging script using function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a button that executes a function, that function in question takes 5 seconds or so to finish and show the data on the page, but the problem is that when it is loading the page lags and the cursor is stuck on the pointer for these few seconds. So I wanted to have a loading animation during this "lag". I tried this :

```
function showColors() {
    var buttons = $('td.details-control');

    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)   {
        if(i == 0) {
            $('#spinner .loading').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>');
        } else if (i == buttons.length-1) {
            if($('#spinner').length > 0){
                $('#spinner .loading').html('');
            }
        }
        buttons[i].click();
    }
}
```

But the animation doesn't work, as calling the function makes the page lag directly and it has no time to show the animation.

Comment: `that function in question takes 5 seconds or so to finish and show the data on the page` this is the problem. It sounds like that script is running synchronously, so the UI cannot update during that time. Make that long-running scrip async instead. I'd suggest using a low-delay `setTimeout()` call. If you want a specific example, please add a simplified version of the logic to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, you answered my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how it's done properly using an async call :

```
function resolveAfter5Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            var buttons = $('td.details-control');

            for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)   {
                resolve(buttons[i].click());
            }
        }, 5000);
    });
}

async function showColors() {
    $('#spinner .loading').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>');

    await resolveAfter5Seconds();

    if($('#spinner').length > 0){
        $('#spinner .loading').html('');
    }

}

showColors()
```

Test example : https://jsfiddle.net/sg2nkrdy/1/